# record was saved to the server, but the response does not have an id and your record does not either

Tags: ember.js, rails-api

I’m facing this error since yesterday, Error: Assertion Failed: 'todo' was saved to the server, but the response does not have an id and your record does not either.

I know it should come from app/serializers/todo.js or my app/routes/application.jsbut after looking into severals forum, I have to ask the question to expert emberJs dev, as i’m a newbie :smiley:

Here’s `my app/serializers/todo.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = this._super.apply(this, arguments); // Get default serialization

    json.id = record.id;  // tack on the id

    return json;
  }
});
```

And my `app/routes/application.js`

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('todo');
  },
    actions: {
      createtodo: function() {

        var titleInput = this.get("newTitle")
        var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
          title: titleInput,
          isCompleted: false
        }); 

        this.set('newTitle', '');
        todo.save();
      }
    }
});
```

The way the createtodo action is triggered `app/templates/application.hbs`:

```
{{input type="text" id="new-todo" value=newTitle}}
<button {{action "createtodo"}}>Save</button>
```

So my objec is created but not save. When i’m looking into my ember Inspector, I see that each object I create have an ID but the title field is null or "".

This is a todoApp with an Rails-API as back and Ember as front.

Anyone see what’s wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer is the problem. If you're using a somewhat standard api setup, you shouldn't really need the serializer at all. I'd delete that first.

What's likely happening is that your API isn't setup to recieve JSON-API documents, which are structured like:

```
{
  id: <id>,
  type: <type>,
  attributes: {
    name: <string>, 
    created: <date>,
    complete: <boolean>
   }
 }
```

So you should either install a json-api gem on the backend or switch the adapter to use the `DS.RestSerializer`, which has a totally flat data structure.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as Enner31 and all of our serializers are JSONAPISerializers, which generally work fine. It's just this model ('appointment' in our case) that throws the error. Deleting the serializer or changing it to RestSerializer didn't help. And now I have no clue where to continue searching for the error. Our backend guy said both request and response look fine and should work.